# Creating a view CSOM Powershell

Tags: powershell, client-object-model

How can I create a view in Powershell using CSOM
This works in server side I am unsure how to do it in CSOM

```
$viewQuery = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsActive" /><ValueType="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where>'
$viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$viewFields.Add("Title")
$viewFields.Add($myFieldPrivacyStatementurl)
$viewFields.Add($myFieldIsActive)
$viewFields.Add($myFieldSortOrder)
```

Here is the code I have so far :

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {

param(

   $ClientObject = $(throw "Please provide an Client Object instance on which to invoke the generic method")

) 

   $ctx = $ClientObject.Context

   $load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 

   $type = $ClientObject.GetType()

   $clientObjectLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod($type) 

   $clientObjectLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($ClientObject,$null))

}

function CreateList()

{

param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials

  )

 $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)

 $ctx.Credentials = $credentials

 $web = $ctx.Web 

 Invoke-LoadMethod -ClientObject $web

 $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$ListInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$ListInfo.Title = $ListTitle
$ListInfo.TemplateType = "100"
$myList = $web.Lists.Add($ListInfo)
$myList.Description = $ListTitle
$myList.Update()
 $Fields=$myList.Fields
$ctx.Load($Fields)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

$myList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='URL' DisplayName='PrivacyStatementUrls' Required='TRUE' />",$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
$myList.Update()

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$myList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Boolean' DisplayName='IsActive' />",$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
$myList.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


$myList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Number' DisplayName='SortOrder'/>",$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
$myList.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()



$ListItemInfo1 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$Item1 = $myList.AddItem($ListItemInfo1)
$Item1["Title"] = "test1"
$Item1["PrivacyStatementUrls"] = "http://www.google.co.uk"
$Item1["IsActive"] = 0
$Item1["SortOrder"] = 1
$Item1.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$ListItemInfo2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$Item2 = $myList.AddItem($ListItemInfo2)
$Item2["Title"] = "test2"
$Item2["PrivacyStatementUrls"] = "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
$Item2["IsActive"] = 1
$Item2["SortOrder"] = 2
$Item2.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$ListItemInfo3 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$Item3 = $myList.AddItem($ListItemInfo3)
$Item3["Title"] = "test3"
$Item3["PrivacyStatementUrls"] = "http://www.skynews.com"
$Item3["IsActive"] = 1
$Item3["SortOrder"] = 3
$Item3.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


}    



$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('name', 'pass')

$url = 'url'

$ListTitle="Privacy Statements"



CreateList $url $credentials
```

Comment: did you try http://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/create-and-delete-sharepoint-list-views-with-powershell/

Comment: doesn't look like CSOM to me

Comment: You want it csom or powershell?

Comment: I want it powershell but client side not server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `ViewCreationInformation` class:

Add this function to your script, and call it after creating the list (after the `ExecuteQuery()` that follows the list creation):

```
function CreateView()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ctx,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$list,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ViewName
    )

    $viewQuery = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsActive" /><ValueType="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where>'
    $viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    $viewFields.Add("Title")

    $ViewInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ViewCreationInformation
    $ViewInfo.Query = $viewQuery
    $ViewInfo.RowLimit = 50
    $ViewInfo.ViewFields = $viewFields // It takes a string array, not sure if a String Collection will work
    $ViewInfo.Title = $ViewName

    $list.Views.Add($ViewInfo)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

I may have messed something up with the PowerShell, it's been awhile.

Comment: What if I have a username and password for the site will this still work?

Comment: SharePoint Online? Or something else?

Comment: my site requires a username and password to logon

Comment: Does my edit help?

Comment: its confusing me as I am trying to add it to the code I have already done. I have added my code to the question