# SharePoint Online Create View PowerShell Vs Quick Edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, list-view

I successfully created a view using a Powershell script on SharePoint Online, in a picture library.
I based my script on these two blog posts to do my script :

[Creating a view CSOM Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104833/creating-a-view-csom-powershell#_=_) and 
[How to create a List View in SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-create-a-List-View-fb4782c9)

My problem is that in both cases, the view doesn't allow to use Quick Edit. In my case, Quick Edit is a must.

Answer (score 0):

What does the TabularView property say?

If you check the XML of the created views, it should show FALSE for views without Quick Edit and TRUE for views with Quick Edit. It seems that by default it is set to FALSE:

```
$ListViewki=$list.Views
$ctx.Load($ListViewki)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($lv in $ListViewki)
{
Write-Output $lv.ListViewXML
}
```

You can use this [New-SPOView](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32366.sharepoint-online-spomod-new-spolistview.aspx) cmdlet. It seems to do the job for me.

[image]

Comment: The TabularView is set to FALSE to the view I created with my script....   Any Idea how to change it with a PowerShell Script ? I do how to set it with powershell ?

Comment: Hey, I have been looking for a way, but I have to admit I hit a dead end. Did you find something, @Merlin?

Comment: No, dead end for me too, thx for trying.

Comment: I found a way, I am using New-SPOListView from here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32366.sharepoint-online-spomod-new-spolistview.aspx. I do not see really much difference between your solution and this, but this works for me. Please let me know the result if you try.